# Convert Pdf into CSV using R

Tags: r, regex, stringr

My pdf table looks like the following:
[image: table]

I'm trying to convert this table into csv file. The code I'm using is the following:

```r
x <- c('pdftools', 'stringr', 'tidyverse')
lapply(x, require, character.only = TRUE)
```

### Reading the file

```r
pdf_text <- pdf_text('Input/file.pdf') %>%
  readr::read_lines()

write.csv(pdf_text ,'pdf_text .csv', row.names = F)
```

Please find the file [link](http://www.filedropper.com/kmr-1989) attached. 
But unfortunately I'm not getting the correct result. I tried many online options suggested. But none worked. Can someone please guide me?

Thanks!

Comment: This is close to reproducible, but nobody can attempt the critical part of using `pdftools` on a file. While I discourage links as a general rule, in this case we need a "real PDF file" in order to test something. Can you provide a link to this PDF file?

Comment: @r2evans: Thanks for your comment. Updated my question accordingly. It's my miss.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`tabulizer`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tabulizer/index.html) package can easily extract tables from PDF.
It will return a list with one element (a matrix) for each page. So we convert the matrix to a dataframe (tibble), then we chop the headers and bind the rows.
We can then transform the values (strings) as numeric...

```
library(tidyverse)
library(tabulizer)

(extract_tables("c:/tmp/KMR-1989.pdf",
                method = "lattice") %>% 
  map(as_tibble) %>% 
  map_dfr(slice, 4:1000) %>% 
  mutate_at(3:19, as.numeric) %>% 
  write_csv("my_pdf.csv"))

#> # A tibble: 44 x 19
#>    V1    V2        V3    V4    V5    V6    V7    V8    V9   V10   V11   V12
#>    <chr> <chr>  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#>  1 1     MALLA~    0   545.  316.  82.9  944.   2.1     0   0     2.1     0
#>  2 2     RAIKAL  321.  741.  226.  92.9 1381.  40.6     0   1.4  42       0
#>  3 3     DHARM~  210.  503   271  187.  1171.   2       0  35.6  37.6     0
#>  4 4     VELGA~  360.  336.  286. 143.  1124.  38       0  23.4  61.4     0
#>  5 5     KAMAN~    0   442.  242. 130    814.   0       0   0     0       0
#>  6 6     MANTH~  297.  394   320. 202   1213.  34.8     0   0    34.8     0
#>  7 7     KATAR~    0   493   468  245   1206   20       0   0    20      17
#>  8 8     MAHAD~  329   534   546  165   1574   28       0   0    28       0
#>  9 9     MUTHA~  260.  293   296  253   1102.  31       0   0    31       0
#> 10 10    PEDDA~  392.  277.  151.  85    905.  10.2     0   0    10.2     0
#> # ... with 34 more rows, and 7 more variables: V13 <dbl>, V14 <dbl>,
#> #   V15 <dbl>, V16 <dbl>, V17 <dbl>, V18 <dbl>, V19 <dbl>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! It solved my problem. `map_dfr` was not working for my case. So, I used `map_df`. The explanation is also wonderful. Thanks again!!